# A question in boolean calculus

Tags: boolean-algebra

I've looked everywhere on the web, in my note and to fellow student without any of them able to explain to me. Here is my question to you.

I can't figure out how to calculate this boolean expression

Can you help me solve : **¬(¬x+x¬y)**    (sorry i don't know LAtex nor can post image.)

I know that the answer is **¬(x+y)** or **¬x¬y**

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to note that $$1+\neg y=1,$$ so $$\neg x=\neg x(1+\neg y)=\neg x+\neg x\neg y.$$ Can you take it from there?

P.S.: The answer isn't what you think.

Comment: Are you sure that the answer is not that, the teacher gave us the answer on a answer sheet

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I think i got it. Thank you very much

Comment: What did you end up with?

Comment: I ended up with ¬x¬y. I went to see my teacher and he did a demo for me. What did you end up with? This thing got me confused a bit.

Comment: Well, using the fact I mentioned, $$\begin{array}\neg(\neg x+x\neg y) &= \neg(\neg x+\neg x\neg y+x\neg y)\\ &= \neg\bigl(\neg x+(\neg x+x)\neg y\bigr)\\ &= \neg(\neg x+1\neg y)\\ &= \neg(\neg x+\neg y)\\ &= \neg\bigl(\neg(xy)\bigr)\\ &= xy.\end{array}$$

Comment: I get it now, i see where i did a mistake. At the end i forgot one ¬ in the expression ¬(¬(xy))

Comment: If it had been $\neg(xy),$ that would have been the same as $\neg x+\neg y,$ not $\neg x\neg y.$ Is the original expression correct? It still surprises me that your teacher's answer key doesn't match.

Comment: I wrote it badly. **xy** is negative. my bad...